# Can't use Shortcut key on linux mint 19 XFCE

Tags: shortcut, system

I am not able to use the shortcut key in Blender, although in *Preferences > Input* there is normal.

For example, I can't use key <kbd>G</kbd> for move , <kbd>S</kbd> for scale, <kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>Y</kbd>, <kbd>Z</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> for duplication, but I can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> and various keys preceded by either Ctrl or Alt..

I have tried many times and more than one time I have to re-install Linux.

How do I solve this issue?

Comment: I can't use some shortcut keys not how to use a shortcut key

Comment: Please read the link. Keyboard shortcuts on the OS take precedence over those of blender. You need to customize linux not to conflict with blender, or customize blender so that it doesn't use keys that are already in use. Also, are you using a custom keyboard layout in the OS? It is unlikey that reinstalling linux or blender is not going to change things.

Comment: The problem is resolved, even though I don't quite understand it. All I have to do is change the interface of the new language to English. All the shortcut keys will work again. Thank you very much for the advice.